# SQL invalid indentifier....?

Tags: oracle

I'm suppose to change the price of Product 121 to $7.50 for Order 100 in OrderDetail

I'm getting this error code

```
SQL> UPDATE OrderDetail_mys
  2    SET ProductPrice = 7.50
  3  WHERE ProductID = 121;
  SET ProductPrice = 7.50
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "PRODUCTPRICE": invalid identifier
```

SQL table for OrderDetail

```
CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
 OrderID    NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductID  NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
 ProductQty NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
 ProdcutPrice   NUMBER(6,2)     NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID, ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY    (OrderID)   REFERENCES Order_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY    (ProductID)     REFERENCES Product_mys
 ) ;
```

Comment: The column is spelled `ProdcutPrice` in the `create table` statement.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error SQL> UPDATE INTO Product_mys
  2    SET ProductName ='BD Claw Hammer'
  3  WHERE ProductID = 'S100';
UPDATE INTO Product_mys
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00903: invalid table name

Comment: you have an unnecessary `INTO` after your `UPDATE`, which is being interpreted as the table name;  which database are you using, mysql or oracle? if you have questions unrelated to your original post, please formulate a complete new question to post

Comment: Why don't you answer the question so I can accept it..? lol

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129